# gdalwarp rpc weird output

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I am applying RPC's via a vrt file and observing a weird output shown here:

[image: test.png]

.

The gdalwarp command I am using is:

```
$ gdalwarp -overwrite -dstalpha -rpc test.vrt test_rpc.tif
```

Here are the links to [VRT file](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506191033/https://s3.amazonaws.com/eo1-hyperion/test/test.vrt)
and the [Test file](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506152253/https://s3.amazonaws.com/eo1-hyperion/test/test.tif).

The top of the image should be shifted to the left and bottom part of image should be shifted to the right.  I am running gdal version 2.1.3.

Comment: I think you are right.  This seems to work much better in degrees. :)  Thank you for pointing this out.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://geotiff.maptools.org/rpc_prop.html and http://geotiff.maptools.org/STDI-0002_v2.1.pdf, the ground coordinates should be in degrees.

Your data does not fit in there.